# Ansible playbook select list by extra var

Tags: ansible

In a file I have store lists to be iterated like this in a vars.yml

```
list_tests:
 - testone
 - testtwo
list_run:
 - runone
   - first
   - second     
 - runtwo
   - alpha
   - beta
```

and a playbook like that

```
- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - name: load vars
      include_vars: "vars.yml"
    - name: with list of items looping
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item[0] }}"
      with_list: "{{ mylist }}"
```

replacing mylist with list_tests or list_runs works fine. I would like to start it like

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -e "mylist=list_run"
```

would it be possible to select the list iteration by setting a var on the command line ? or even the list of lists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to parse all the items from each list, then you have to set list variable like

```
  - list_run:
    - ["first","second"]
    - ["alpha"," beta"]
```

and to

```
  tasks:
    - name: with list of items looping
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ vars[mylist] }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> would it be possible to select the list iteration by setting a var on the command line ?

Yes, you just have to update the `with_list:` to not use a concrete variable, but rather look it up in the `vars` dict:

```
- debug: var=item
  with_list: '{{ vars[mylist] }}'
```